# Getting undefined in console after selecting list item

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript programming and while practicing DOM selectors i encountered a problem which is, after selecting the list items, i am adding EventListner to each of the list item, but when i am printing listItem variable inside the EventListner function it prints undefined in console, but when i try to print the listItem variable outside the EventListner function, it prints fine.

i tried to figure out this problem by searching several answers on stack overflow, but i couldn't figure out this problem.

I am trying to get listItem on console instead of undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//JavaScript

```
    var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
    var enter = document.getElementById("enter");
    var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
    function addListItemOnClick() {
        if (input.value.length > 0) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
            ul.appendChild(li);
            input.value = " ";
        }
    }
    function addListItemOnPress() {
        if (input.value.length > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
            ul.appendChild(li);
            input.value = " ";
        }
    }
    enter.addEventListener("click", addListItemOnClick);
    input.addEventListener("keypress", addListItemOnPress);

    var liItem = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < liItem.length; i++) {
        liItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log(liItem[i]); // prints undefined
        });

        // console.log(liItem[i]); //works fine
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yhg9ok4/

Comment: The problem is that `i` within the event handler will be `liItem.length`, see the linked question's answers for why and how to fix it. (Although in your specific case, just use `this` instead of `liItem[i]`.)

Comment: try `console.log(this)`

Comment: @JamalAbo What will that show? `this` isn't even being referenced.

Comment: @DaveNewton - If the OP replaces `console.log(liItem[i]);` in their click handler with `console.log(this);`, they'll get the result they were expecting.

Comment: @DaveNewton `this` refers to the HTMLDom Object, which in this case the `<li>` that was clicked,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh in the handler; gotcha.